# How to Create an intent for broadcast receiver?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have a class with a broadcast receiver class inside of it. How would I go about creating an intent to call upon the broadcast receiver from my on create in the same class?

Answer (score 1):

Create intent in usual way and send it with 
[sendBroadcast(Intent)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#sendBroadcast%28android.content.Intent%29) method of [Context](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html) class